# Open Safari app on iPhone from Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, safari, apple-watch

I know you can't open your own app if it's not already open, but is it possible to open a default Apple app on the phone with a link from the Apple Watch app?

Answer (score 0):

You can open Safari using `UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"yourCustomLink")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`
I don't know much about watch app but I am sure that you can make communication between your iPhone and Watch using `WatchConnectivity`.
Send the link from the watch to ur iPhone. Open link using the code snippet. Voilà.